# Saving TextView contents in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making a to-do list app and I have a tableview with custom cells in it. The custom cells only have a textview where the user can input their "tasks". Also, the user can add rows for more tasks and delete rows if he/she has completed that task on the list. However if the app is closed the tableview is reset obviously, and the user losses everything he/she has written in the cells before. This way, the app is pretty much useless.

**My question is:** How could I preserve the text in each cell's TextView even after the app was closed?

**EDIT:** I managed to save the data in `NSUserDefaults` by iterating through every cell's `textview` and getting their `text` property. However the problem is that if I load the data on startup into an `array` and populate the cell's `textviews` from that `array` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the text in `textviews` are reset(to the data that was loaded on startup) whenever the user scrolls the tableview as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called again.

**So my question is now:** How could I overcome this issue? I would only need to populate the tableView on startup not every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

My code:

I wrote a separate method for saving the contents of the cells (notes is just an empty mutable array).

```
-(void)saveNotes{
   NSArray *cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
    [notes removeAllObjects];

    for (TableViewCell *cell in cells)
    {
        [notes addObject:cell.textView.text];
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setObject:notes forKey:@"notes"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
        NSLog(@"notes saved!");
    }
}
```

Than in `viewDidLoad` I set the tableview's dataSource array to be the one that is stored in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([userDefaults objectForKey:@"notes"]){
        dataSource = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"notes"] mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"Notes loaded");
    }
    else{
        dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"", nil];
        NSLog(@"Nothing found! :(");
    }
```

After that, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I set the textviews of all the cells to show the text thats was loaded in `viewDidLoad`:

```
cell.textView.text = [dataSource objectAtIndex[indexPath row]];
```

Comment: store value in nsuserdefaluts

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Anyone? Please I am ready to publish the app if it wasn't for this little problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to solve my own question by a really simple `if` statement. I made an ivar in the header file of my ViewController named `didHaveUserInteraction`. I set this in my `viewDidLoad` to `FALSE`. And in the textview delegate method: `textViewDidChange` I set it to `TRUE`. Than, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I wrote:

```
if(!didHaveUserInteraction){
        cell.textView.text = [dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
```

By doing this, the cells only get populated with the saved data on startup or if the user has not modified anything in any of the `TextViews` yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have many choices either you use `NSFileManager()`, `Core Data`, they both will save your data internally (on the actual device)   or actual Database (**Parse.com**) this will be save on a sever.

> To answer the second part of your question

you could create a `queryFunction() or Retrieve function` that would be into `ViewDidLoad()` so once the app becomes active it will get all the data then show it into the `UITableViewCell`

> to Retrieve from NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"notes"]];
>   then assign that **resultArray** into the array you use to populate data into the viewDidLoad

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully, could you show me some code for the queryFunction in viewDidLoad?

Comment: So I should do  `dataSource = resultArray` in `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: yes Sir or **self.dataSource =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notes"]];**

Comment: Thanks, but I am already doing that in my code: `NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([userDefaults objectForKey:@"notes"]){
        dataSource = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"notes"] mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"Notes loaded");
    }
    else{
        dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"", nil];
        NSLog(@"Nothing found! :(");
    }`

Comment: so called into your viewDidLoad... so it will get all your data in populate into your cell

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing already but the problem is that I can't populate the cell from viewDidLoad only from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: try to this : in your save function comment the code you have ... simply hard code two or three values  then synchronize it **dont use any tableviecell code** only values into the array + **[self.tableView reloadData];** then save it then put the retrieve notes into the viewDidLoad and try to run the code and see

Comment: I was doing that originally, it didn't work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Before the app will get closed, in you app delegate, precisally in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` you can save all of the user data, the data can be saved in a .plist file or in `NSUserDefaults` for more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html)
So basically you while the user it's editing the list, you can save all the info in temporary data structure, such as Array, the when the app will get closed, save the data persistently. When user will open the app again, in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` reload that data that you've previously saved.

Comment: This would be good but it's the same as doing it form viewDidLoad which is impossible because both of them are called before the tableview is even set up.

Comment: you can do it in viewWillAppare or in applicationWillBecameActive in AppDelegate. if you app it's gonne use the data on inly one viewController you can use viewWillAppare otherwise if you need to use the data in more than one ViewController you can use applicationWillBecameActive